# I don't doubt but you'll do it

Tags: conjunctions, negation

> **BUT** (conjunction)
>
> 6. *that* (used esp. after words like *doubt, deny*, etc., with a negative word like *not*):
>
> *I don't doubt **but** you'll do it.*
>
> https://www.wordreference.com/definition/but

Isn't the example ambiguous with the alternative meaning *"the only thing I doubt is that/whether you are able to do it"*?

Comment: There is no alternative meaning. It is not: I doubt that you'll be able to do it.

Comment: *"I don't doubt **anything** but (except for) you'll do it."* - I don't know how grammatical and common it is, but it would require *anything*.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko can you elaborate? For what meaning exactly?

Comment: @GJC e.g. She is anything but nice (She isn't nice), I don't do anything but sleep (I sleep all the time). In my (questionably reasonable) example, it would mean "I really doubt you will do it".

Comment: @AndrewTobilko No, anything is not required and that is really not very grammatical. I don't understand why these things have to be dragged out when it is patently clear to a native speaker that there is nothing ambiguous about: I don't doubt but you'll do it. for: the fact you will do it.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko That'd be a different meaning [other than](https://www.wordreference.com/definition/but) or even an idiom https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/anything+but

Answer (score 4):

This case of the word **but** isn't used very often (at least not by me). You can say:

- I don't doubt **but** you'll do it.
- I don't doubt **that** you'll do it.
- I don't doubt you'll do it.
- I have no doubt you'll do it.

They all have the same meaning. You just won't hear the first one very often.

Comment: Right, and it will never mean: be able to do it. Nothing about being able at all.

Comment: What does _I doubt **but** you'll do it_ mean then?  _When the main clause is negative or interrogative, doubt could
also formerly be followed by **but that** _ https://books.google.es/books?id=AvmzBgAAQBAJ&lpg=PA236&ots=gKt6PVkvtg&dq=%22When%20the%20main%20clause%20is%20negative%20or%20interrogative%2C%20doubt%20could%20also%20formerly%20be%20followed%22&hl=es&pg=PA236#v=onepage&q=%22When%20the%20main%20clause%20is%20negative%20or%20interrogative,%20doubt%20could%20also%20formerly%20be%20followed%22&f=false

Answer (score 1):

This usage of *but* is so unfamiliar to me that I had to look it up in the Oxford English Dictionary.  The example you cited corresponds to sense C.9b in the OED:

> but, *prep., adv., conj., and n.2*
>
> C. *conj.*
>
> Ⅱ. In a complex sentence, introducing a subordinate clause.
>
> 9. After various verbs in negative or interrogative constructions, reversing the effect of the negative or interrogative so as to affirm
>    more emphatically the dependent clause (e.g. *I don't know but she's
>    got notions into her head* = ‘I think it likely that she's got notions
>    into her head’). Frequently in ***but that***.
>
>    a.
>
>    (a) After verbs and verbal phrases expressing mental affirmation, as *believe, be sure, conceive, conclude, persuade, say,
>    see, think, wit,* and (esp.) *know*. Now *rare* (chiefly *regional*).
>
>    (b) After *deny*. Now *rare*.
>    In this use, *but* has the effect of affirming the dependent clause without cancelling the preceding negative.
>
>    b. After verbs and verbal phrases expressing *dubiety, as doubt, despair, scruple.* Cf. sense C.9d.
>        <sup>[Compare classical Latin *non dubito quin* ‘I don't doubt that’.]</sup>
>
>    ⋮
>        1932 R. Macaulay: Shadow Flies i. xviii. 159.   No question but the witch'll walk, starkling all the countryside.
>        2009 P. Glennie & N. Thrift: [Shaping the Day](https://www.worldhistory.org/books/0199278202/) ii. 56.   There is
>    no question but that the striking of the clock would have been
>    familiar to Roger Martin.
>
>    c. After verbs and phrases expressing prevention.
>
>    †(a) After *God forbid,* and similar expressions. *Obsolete.*
>
>    †(b) After *hinder, prevent, restrain,* etc. (now followed by *from* with the gerund, or the gerund alone). Also after *fail,
>    forbear, hold,* etc. (now followed by an infinitive or gerund with or
>    without *from*). Often with infinitive as verb of the dependent
>    clause. *Obsolete.*
>
>    †(c) After *I see not* or *I see no cause.* *Obsolete.*
>
>    †(d) After *there wanted but little.* *Obsolete.*
>
>    (e) After *cannot help* (see HELP *v.* 11b).
>
>    d. After *fear* and †*dread*. Cf. sense C.9b. Now *rare.*

Basically, it's saying that this usage of *but* really is uncommon, and becoming archaic, if it isn't already.  Even their most recent citation prefers *but that* for clarity.  I think most people these days would simply prefer *that* without *but*.

Comment: https://oed.com/oed2/00030107

Comment: @GJC I cited the OED Third Edition (2018). In the Second Edition (1989) that you linked to, it's sense 21.